# Anchor tags suddenly not working on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Suddenly my site is in shambles. I had a temp url and replaced it with the permanent url. Someone else is using the old temp url and their content is showing on my site http://chocolateandwinefest.com . The anchor tags arent working on my site as well. They were previously. I have uninstalled all of the plugins one by one and switched themes. The problem still exists. Can someone please trouble shoot my site and let me know why the anchor tags aren't working?

I have uninstalled all plugins and deactivated the theme.

Comment: Was this after a migration? It sounds like you have some URLs left over from the temp url.

Comment: No...we just started the site with the temp url provided by the host because we didnt have a domain name yet from the client. One button still isn't working, the one labeled "sign up to be a vendor". Any ideas?

Comment: I would query the database with phpMyAdmin for that temp url and replace it if found.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did that. I replaced every single url in the db. Any other ideas?

Comment: The link for that sign up button must be hardcoded in a template if it is not in the database.

Comment: It is hardcoded in a template. I am using wpbakery and the button link works. If I put another url there, it navigates to that url. But for some reason, it cannot find that anchor. Other buttons on the page find the location but for some reason that 'a' tag can't. Any suggestions?

Comment: WpBakery takes you into the configuration realm. From a coding perspective the best option is to destroy every copy of wpbakery. Sorry I would not be able to diagnose a page builder remotely.

Comment: I would start a thread on WPBakery's forums. SO is only for code. Configuration is out of scope.